# Segmentation fault in std::less<char>

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have the following code (C++0x):

```
const set<char> s_special_characters =  { '(', ')', '{', '}', ':' };

void nectar_loader::tokenize( string &line, const set<char> &special_characters )
{
    auto it = line.begin();
    const auto not_found = special_characters.end();

    // first character special case
    if( it != line.end() && special_characters.find( *it ) != not_found )
        it = line.insert( it+1, ' ' ) + 1;

    while( it != line.end() )
    {
        // check if we're dealing with a special character
        if( special_characters.find(*it) != not_found ) // <----------
        {
            // ensure a space before
            if( *(it-1) != ' ' )
                it = line.insert( it, ' ' ) + 1;
            // ensure a space after
            if( (it+1) != line.end() && *(it+1) != ' ' )
                it = line.insert( it+1, ' ');
            else
                line.append(" ");
        }
        ++it;
    }
}
```

with the crash pointing at the indicated line. This results in a segfault with this gdb backtrace:

```
#0  0x000000000040f043 in std::less<char>::operator() (this=0x622a40, __x=@0x623610, __y=@0x644000)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_function.h:230
#1  0x000000000040efa6 in std::_Rb_tree<char, char, std::_Identity<char>, std::less<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_lower_bound (this=0x622a40, __x=0x6235f0, __y=0x622a48, __k=@0x644000)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1020
#2  0x000000000040e840 in std::_Rb_tree<char, char, std::_Identity<char>, std::less<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find (this=0x622a40, __k=@0x644000)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_tree.h:1532
#3  0x000000000040e4fd in std::set<char, std::less<char>, std::allocator<char> >::find (this=0x622a40, __x=@0x644000)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_set.h:589
#4  0x000000000040de51 in ambrosia::nectar_loader::tokenize (this=0x7fffffffe3b0, line=..., special_characters=...)
    at ../../ambrosia/Library/Source/Ambrosia/nectar_loader.cpp:146
#5  0x000000000040dbf5 in ambrosia::nectar_loader::fetch_line (this=0x7fffffffe3b0)
    at ../../ambrosia/Library/Source/Ambrosia/nectar_loader.cpp:112
#6  0x000000000040dd11 in ambrosia::nectar_loader::fetch_token (this=0x7fffffffe3b0, token=...)
    at ../../ambrosia/Library/Source/Ambrosia/nectar_loader.cpp:121
#7  0x000000000040d9c4 in ambrosia::nectar_loader::next_token (this=0x7fffffffe3b0)
    at ../../ambrosia/Library/Source/Ambrosia/nectar_loader.cpp:72
#8  0x000000000040e472 in ambrosia::nectar_loader::extract_nectar<std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<ambrosia::target> > > (this=0x7fffffffe3b0, it=...)
    at ../../ambrosia/Library/Source/Ambrosia/nectar_loader.cpp:43
#9  0x000000000040d46d in ambrosia::drink_nectar<std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<ambrosia::target> > > (filename=..., it=...)
    at ../../ambrosia/Library/Source/Ambrosia/nectar.cpp:75
#10 0x00000000004072ae in ambrosia::reader::event (this=0x623770)
```

I'm at a loss, and have no clue where I'm doing something wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: the string at the moment of the crash is

> sub Ambrosia : lib libAmbrosia

UPDATE:

I replaced the above function following suggestions in comments/answers. Below is the result.

```
const string tokenize( const string &line, const set<char> &special_characters )
{
    const auto not_found = special_characters.end();
    const auto end = line.end();
    string result;

    if( !line.empty() )
    {
        // copy first character
        result += line[0];

        char previous = line[0];
        for( auto it = line.begin()+1; it != end; ++it )
        {
            const char current = *it;

            if( special_characters.find(previous) != not_found )
                result += ' ';

            result += current;
            previous = current;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the string passed to `nectar_loader::tokenize` on the occasion of the segfault? (It's not visible in the backtrace above.)

Comment: added string contents to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another guess is that `line.append(" ")` will sometimes invalidate `it`, depending on the original capacity of the line.

Comment: `insert` can invalidate iterators too.

Comment: @Gareth: that's why I'm taking the `return`ed iterator on calls to insert. I couldn't for an append call.

Comment: @rubenvb: oh yes, so you are; sorry.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's the most likely culprit, although in the specific case where it crashes it doesn't seem very likely.

Answer (score 2):

You don't check that `it != line.end()` before the first time you dereference `it`.

Comment: True, but it's hard to see how that could produce a segfault at the point rubenvb claims the error is at. (Of course we don't know absolutely for sure that that's the real location of the error.)

Comment: Might be, but adding that check to the first if: `if( it != line.end() && special_characters... )` does not fix the crash `:(`. I also tried the first if inside the loop. No change in either case.

Comment: Edited the first if. The next if (first in the loop) doesn't need the check, as the while condition already did, but the next if needs a way to check for an invalid iterator. Could I check for `it >= line.begin()` or something?

Comment: The reason that it segfaults inside `find` instead of `*i` is that `find` takes its argument by reference. The code is just passing around an address that points to invalid memory, but it won't crash until it tries to read from that address.

Answer (score 0):

I could not spot the error, I would suggest iterating slowly with the debugger since you have identitied the issue.

I'll just that in general, modifying what you are iterating over is extremely prone to failure.

I'd recommend using [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/index.html), and more precisely: [`boost::token_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/token_iterator.htm) combined with [`boost::char_separator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/tokenizer/char_separator.htm) (code example included).

You could then simply build a new `string` from the first, and return the new string from the function. The speed up on computation should cover the memory allocation.

Comment: I have thought of subclassing an `istream` or (`stream_buf`, the one that's supposed to be subclassed) and work from a much lower level (the subclass's `operator>>`). Wouldn't that be a better STL solution in this case?

Comment: @rubenvb: I don't know enough about the intrisics of `istream`. It seems more difficult to add optional behavior (like full trimming on both ends).